# Do Wii games have different boxes in Japan and USA(or other countries)?

Tags: nintendo-wii

I saw Super Mario Galaxy unboxing(Japanese version) and I realized that it got a cardboard box like old console games and then I looked for the USA version and no box.

Do Wii games have different in "looks" basing on the country it was produced? And also Different art on the box/casing?

Comment: Was it some sort of special edition?  As far as I'm aware, Super Mario Galaxy has just a DVD-style case in JP.

Comment: @Powerlord This is the link that I saw. https://youtu.be/Y8do33xXqw4
I'm not sure this is a special edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, box art usually varies by region, like the U.S., Japan, or Europe.